# Populate dropdown with Microsoft Access values - HTML & PHP

Tags: php, html, odbc, dropdown, populate

I'm doing my best trying to populate a dropdown from my access db using php and html.

I have a table in my DATA.mdb that I've named CONTACTS and it contains 4 columns and some rows, as below:

Id    Person    Phone    Email    



10    Pers1     112         mail1    



10    Pers2     113         mail2    



10    Pers3     114         mail3    



20    Pers4     211         mail4    



20    Pers5     311         mail5

When I enter 10 to my input="text" I get an echo that looks like this: 
**Pers1Pers2Pers3**

and when I enter 20 I get
**Pers4Pers5**

This is what i've manage to do with the PHP:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['n01_text'])) 
{
ob_start();
$stxt = rtrim($_POST['n01_text']);

$keys = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $stxt);

//- Open DATA
$db = odbc_connect('DATA','','') or die(odbc_errormsg());

//- Read CONTACTS
$sql = "SELECT ID, Person, Phone, Email FROM CONTACTS WHERE ID= '" . $ID. "'";
$rs = odbc_exec($db,$sql) or die(odbc_errormsg());

    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) { 
    $Person= odbc_result($rs,"Person");     
    $Phone= odbc_result($rs,"Phone");   
    $Email = odbc_result($rs,"Email "); 

echo $Person;
}

odbc_close($db);
ob_end_flush();
}
?>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text"name="n01_text" placeholder="ID" class="findtext" id="contact"> <span id="myspan" class="input-group-addon">Search</span>

<select>
<option value=0><?php echo $Person; ?></option>                         
<!-- Populate from Access-->
</select>
```

From this code, I only get the last entry from the db to my dropdown, which is **Pers3** for ID 10 and **Pers5** for ID 20.

I really don't have any clue of how to solve this.

I am trying my best to learn and I am sure there a tons of way my code can improve and I appreciate all kinds of corrections, but please be patient with me!

Comment: your db code only echoes the person's name. it doesn't echo ANY html necessary to make those names into `<option>` for the `<select>`. and you need to show how those two code chunks ACTUALLY hang together.

Comment: why do you need the output buffer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
$Person .= "<option value=$i>".odbc_result($rs,"Person")."</option>";
$i++;
```

and then update the HTML to:

```
<input type="text"name="n01_text" placeholder="ID" class="findtext" id="contact"> <span id="myspan" class="input-group-addon">Search</span>

<select>
<?php echo $Person; ?>
<!-- Populate from Access-->
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this, it gives the same result in the dropdown. but the echo output of $Person changed from being Pers1Pers2Pers3 to Pers1

Comment: Sorry! .... to Pers1 Pers2 and Pers 3 on separate rows. The output is also duplicated.

Comment: My bad, I had an other error... And your solution works perfectly! Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Im glad, I could help :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but does it differ much if I want to insert a row and a value in the access?

Comment: Hey! sorry I dont really get your question? like differ from what? the code you are working on? or from other RDBMs ? Can you explain a little more?